# Unix domain Socket not working on Android 9 (API level 28)

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-9.0-pie, unix-socket

I have two android apllication ( client and a server ) that are connected by Unix domain  socket on the native level (C++/JNI). Both were built using target API level 27 and were working fine for years. Recently I have upgraded them to API level 28 and now I the client can't connect to the server the connect() function return -1 . If I just change all build dependencies to use lower API levels (<=27) it connects correctly. From what i've read on the behavior changes for Android 9 I don't really know what could cause such a thing. Here is the log that i get from logcat.

```
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::open()
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::unix_open()
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::openConnection()
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::setLinger()
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::setNoDelay()
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::structlen = static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof(address)) 110
com.company.client I/TSOCKET:  TSocket::openConnection() connect() return -1
```

I know that API 28 requests run time permissions, and both the service and the app request and get write, read, and internet runtime permissions.

My client manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.company.client"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="5.1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.client.clientActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my server manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.server"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="5.1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FILTER_EVENTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <permission android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name="com.company.server.autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.company.server.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:isolatedProcess="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/devices_filter" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/devices_filter" />
        </service>

    </application> </manifest>
```

how can I make the local socket connection to work?

Comment: How do you open the socket? It has a pseudo *path*, which must be accessible for both **client** and **server** apps. Even though they come from the same company, the Android 9 OS does not know that they are related, and the path you have been using before, is not appropriate for one or both apps.

Comment: @AlexCohn
I open the socket using the folowing code 
socket_ = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

const char name[] = "\0local.socket.address";
struct sockaddr_un address = {0};
socklen_t structlen;
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
memcpy(address.sun_path, name, sizeof(name) - 1); 
structlen = sizeof(address.sun_family) + sizeof(name) - 1;   
 
connect(socket_, (struct sockaddr *) &address, structlen);

Comment: I believe this is the change described here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#per-app-selinux. At any rate, Unix Sockets continue to work for apps targeting API 28 and 29, within such app, but not across the apps. You may need to switch to an alternative IPC mechanism.

Comment: After some search on Internet, it seems that latest Android version have probably blocked IPC used (based on thrift with abstract socket) in SELinux rules, The only way to bypass this is probably to use legacy Android IPC mechanism such as Messenger or something equivalent.

Comment: The official IPC mechanism on Android is **binder**. You have NdkBinder, too. See a simple demo: https://github.com/gburca/BinderDemo.

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn for the support